# Wrong currency displayed for old customer orders. How can this be changed?

Tags: orders, currency

I'm currently working on a new Magento ecommerce solution for our website.  Basically, I've migrated all the old data over using a tool for this purpose.  However, the old orders have come over having a currency of $.  I'm not sure why, as the base currency etc was set to £.

In any case, to fix it, the migration tool support suggested a re-migration of all the data again, not just the orders.  However, we've updated the Magento data a fair amount and didn't really want to migrate again.  So I'm wondering if there is another, safe solution to change older orders' currency, so it displays in £ and not $.

Thanks!

EDIT: Ok so on inspecting the table sales_flat_order, I can see that old orders have "USD" in the columns base_currency_code, global_currency_code, order_currency_code and store_currency_code.  I'm simply planning to update the values in these columns to have the value "GBP" (after backing up the table first of course!).

Comment: Maybe the old orders were placed using $ and not  £

Comment: Sadly, the old orders are in £.  The old orders were migrated from a Volusion store (an American website, but it's probably clutching at straws to suggest that could be why!).

Answer (score 1):

I updated two tables to update currencies. These were sales_flat_order and sales_flat_order_grid.  Now the old orders show the correct currency in the Magento backend.